# I made this code and i'm asking if someone can help me to not repeat the function because i need to use different values of k2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, graph

i did this code and i need to use different values of k2 and only use one function .Without repeating the same function 3 times .Because k2 influence the curve of every graph.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def F(Y,t):
  k2=[3,6,9]
  T1=15
  p1=15
  p2=4
  for i in k2:
      return np.array([ -p1*Y[1]*Y[0] -p2*Y[2]*Y[0] , p1*Y[1]*Y[0]-Y[1]*(1/T1) , p2*Y[2]*Y[0]-Y[2]*(1/T1)+p2*k2*Y[2]*Y[1]*(1/T1)])

T=np.linspace(0,140,100)
conditions_initiales = [0.8 , 0.01 ,10**-7]
Y=odeint(F,np.array(conditions_initiales),T)
u=Y[:,0]                 
y2=Y[:,2]
plt.plot(T,y2)                  
plt.legend(['y2','z2','v2'])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Temps en jours ')
plt.title("La propagation de deux variants ")
plt.show()
```

and this code gave me this error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Comment: Pass them (T1, p1, p2 and k2) as arguments, like you do for Y?

Comment: i've tried to pass K2 as an argument but it didn't work . a=F(Y,t,0.3)
G=F(Y,t,0.6)
W=F(Y,t,0.9)
Y=odeint(a,np.array(conditions_initiales),T)
Z=odeint(G,np.array(conditions_initiales),T)
V=odeint(W,np.array(conditions_initiales),T) with F has 3 argument F(Y,t,K2):

Comment: Post the code that is failing, properly formatted, in your question.  Describe what happens and how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra arguments through `odeint()` with the `args` parameter:

```python
def F(Y, t, k2):
    T1 = 15
    p1 = 0.15
    p2 = 0.4
    return np.array([-p1*Y[1]*Y[0]-p2*Y[2]*Y[0], p1*Y[1]*Y[0]-Y[1]*(1/T1), p2*Y[2]*Y[0]-Y[2]*(1/T1)+p2*k2*Y[2]*Y[1]*(1/T1)])

T = np.linspace(0, 140, 100)
conditions_initiales = np.array([0.8, 0.01, 10**-7])
Y = odeint(F, conditions_initiales, T, args=(0.3,))
Z = odeint(F, conditions_initiales, T, args=(0.6,))
V = odeint(F, conditions_initiales, T, args=(0.9,))
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i wasn't aware of the args parameter .